# Looking for sample code or documentation for gpxpy waypoint extension data?

Tags: python, references

I am translating some of my Ruby scripts that manipulate GPX files into Python so I can use them from within QGIS but I can't find any detailed documentation.  The [readme](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy) on github gives a few very basic examples and leaves it at that.  In particular I am trying to figure out how to access extension data for waypoints.

I wondered if anyone had made their own cheat sheet that they would care to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of examples in [test.py](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/test.py). For example [here](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/test.py#L2104).

But note that gpxpy will parse only simple extensions and store them in the extensions field (as a dictionary). Complex extensions are ignored at the moment ([link](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues/73)).

I'll probably implement a solution for complex extensions in the future, but at the moment this issue not on top of my priorities.

Comment: I may be able to help with the coding for the extension stuff.  I also have an interest in improving the ruby GPX module extension handling too.  I am an experienced developer, but not using python.